# How to switch on System.Type?

Tags: c#

In C# 7+, can I switch directly on a `System.Type`?

When I try:

```
    switch (Type)
    {
      case typeof(int):
        break;
    }
```

it tells me that `typeof(int)` needs to be a constant expression.

Is there some syntatic sugar that allows me to avoid `case nameof(int):` and directly compare the types for equality? `nameof(T)` in a case statement is not completely good because namespaces. So although name collision is probably not be applicable for `int`, it will be applicable for other comparisons.

In other words, I'm trying to be more type-safe than this:

```
    switch (Type.Name)
    {
      case nameof(Int32):
      case nameof(Decimal):
        this.value = Math.Max(Math.Min(0, Maximum), Minimum); // enforce minimum 
        break;
    }
```

Comment: @Servy, no I don't. My example isn't the answer. It's the counter-example.

Comment: Rather than using a switch, can you build a `Dictionary<Type, Action>` that calls the function you want for a given type? Your code would be cleaner that way, I think.

Comment: @toddmo `it tells me that typeof(int) needs to be a constant expression.` That's literally the answer to your question.

Comment: @xxbbcc, I've seen that approach. I don't think that's cleaner. It seems a little convoluted. I'm looking for what's built into the switch statement, which so far isn't all that well documented.

Comment: It's described here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2016/08/24/whats-new-in-csharp-7-0/ Switch statements with pattern

Comment: @toddmo I'm just curious, why do you think it's convoluted? I personally find it very flexible and clean to read but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @Matthias247, that doesn't give an example that works directly on `System.Type`. The example given only works on subclasses like with polymorphism.

Comment: @toddmo When comparing two possible implementations, my personal preference has been to go with the solution that actually works over the one that either doesn't compile or doesn't work properly.  By all means choose the "cleaner" solution when comparing two solutions that compile and actually produce the correct output.

Comment: @toddmo Maybe you should explain why you want to switch on `System.Type`, when you can just switch on the value? I guess you would need `typeof(value)` before.

Comment: Can you expand on your code a little bit and tell us more of what the function is supposed to do? Are you just checking Int32 and decimal?

Comment: @Matthias247, in this block I don't have a value; `this.value` hasn't been set. So I can't switch on `this.value`.

Comment: @Magnus, if the Type is int or decimal, I want to enforce the minimum and maximum on the value. If you need more context than that let me know.

Comment: See @Servy, I was right. There's some sugar that's not in the example on switch in the "what's new in c# 7" article that's more direct than the name.

Comment: Why not use an `if`?

Comment: @Magnus, Just personal preference I suppose. in actuality, there may be more cases. `if` results in more sets of brackets being used and the use of `else if`, which, in my mind, becomes not a single selector, but a series of unrelated tests (that's how my mind compiles an `if` block). After all, that's why `switch` was created, to simplify a selector based on a single criteria. `if` blocks can introduce any arbitrary criteria; so when reading the code you have to look harder to ensure you understand what it's really doing.

Answer (score 135, accepted):

The (already linked) new pattern matching feature allows this.

Ordinarily, you'd switch on a value:

```
switch (this.value) {
  case int intValue:
    this.value = Math.Max(Math.Min(intValue, Maximum), Minimum);
    break;
  case decimal decimalValue:
    this.value = Math.Max(Math.Min(decimalValue, Maximum), Minimum);
    break;
}
```

But you can use it to switch on a type, if all you have is a type:

```
switch (type) {
  case Type intType when intType == typeof(int):
  case Type decimalType when decimalType == typeof(decimal):
    this.value = Math.Max(Math.Min(this.value, Maximum), Minimum);
    break;
}
```

Note that this is not what the feature is intended for, it becomes less readable than a traditional `if`...`else if`...`else if`...`else` chain, and the traditional chain is what it compiles to anyway. I do not recommend using pattern matching like this.

Comment: Can you chain `when`s? Instead of `case Type t when (t == typeof(int) || t == typeof(decimal)) :`

Comment: @toddmo (Responding to your edited comment) With `||` it's not what chaining would be, but any condition is valid, including one composed of multiple subexpressions combined using `&&`, `||`, and any other operator you like.

Comment: Why do you declare fresh `Type` variable instead of using discard pattern: `case var _ when type == typeof(int)`?

Comment: @PetSerAl In the general case: to prevent the switch value from being evaluated multiple times. In this case: I don't know if it would be better, but it probably at least wouldn't be worse than what I put in my answer. I still wouldn't use either though.

Answer (score 63):

The issue raised here by the OP is that you can't use the new **C# 7** type-based switch feature when you don't have an actual ***instance*** of the switched-upon type available, and you instead have only its putative `System.Type`. The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43080709/147511), summarized as follows, works well for exact type matching (minor improvement shown here, but see my final example below for yet further streamlining)...

```
Type type = ...
switch (type)
{
    case Type _ when type == typeof(Int32):
    case Type _ when type == typeof(Decimal):
        this.value = Math.Max(Math.Min(this.value, Maximum), Minimum);
        break;
}
```

The important point to note is that for derived reference type hierarchies, this will ***not*** exhibit the same behavior as an `if... else` chain which uses the `is` keyword for matching. Consider:

```
class TBase { }
class TDerived1 : TBase { }
class TDerived2 : TBase { }
sealed class TDerived3 : TDerived2 { }

TBase inst = ...

if (inst is TDerived1)
{
    // Handles case TDerived1
}
else if (inst is TDerived2)
{
    // Handles cases TDerived2 and TDerived3
}
else if (inst is TDerived3)
{
    // IMPOSSIBLE (never executed)               <---  !
}
```

Since `TDerived3` "is-a" `TDerived2`, when using `is` matching, both cases are handled by the second branch. Since `TDerived3` is marked "sealed" in this example, no instance can ever match the third branch.

This highlights the difference at runtime between 'strict' or 'exact' ***type equality*** versus the more nuanced notion of [***type subsumption***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subtyping) (type "compatibility"). Because the types in the OP's question were `ValueType` primitives (which can't be derived-from), the difference couldn't matter. But if we adapt the 'exact type matching' of the accepted answer with the example classes shown above, we *will* get a different result:

```
Type type = ...

switch (type)
{
    case Type _ when type == typeof(TDerived1):
        // Handles case TDerived1
        break;

    case Type _ when type == typeof(TDerived2):
        // Handles case TDerived2
        break;

    case Type _ when type == typeof(TDerived3):
        // Handles case TDerived3                 <---  !
        break;
}
```

In fact, **C# 7** won't even compile a `switch` statement which corresponds to the `if / else` sequence shown earlier. (*n.b.* It seems like the compiler should detect this as a *warning*, rather than an *error*, since the harmless result is just a branch of inaccessible code--a condition which the compiler deems a warning elsewhere--and also considering that the compiler doesn't even detect, at all, the seemingly identical situation in the `if / else` version). Here's that:

[image]

In any case, which one of the alternate behaviors is appropriate, or if it even matters, will depend on your application, so my point here is just to draw attention to the distinction. If you determine that you need the more savvy *type-compatibility* version of the switch approach, here is how to do it:

```
Type type = ...

switch (type)
{
    case Type _ when typeof(TDerived1).IsAssignableFrom(type):
        // Handles case TDerived1
        break;

    case Type _ when typeof(TDerived2).IsAssignableFrom(type):
        // Handles cases TDerived2 and TDerived3
        break;

    case Type _ when typeof(TDerived3).IsAssignableFrom(type):
        // IMPOSSIBLE (never executed)            <---  !
        break;
}
```

As before, the third case is extraneous, since `TDerived3` is sealed for the current example.

Finally, as I mentioned in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53842666/147511) on this page, you can simplify this usage of the `switch` statement even further. Since we're only using the `when` clause functionality, and since we presumably still have the original switched-upon `Type` instance available in a variable, there's no need to mention that variable in the `switch` statement, nor repeat its Type (`Type`, in this case) in each `case`.  Just do the following instead:

```
Type type = ...

switch (true)
{
    case true when typeof(TDerived1).IsAssignableFrom(type):
        break;

    case true when typeof(TDerived2).IsAssignableFrom(type):
        break;

    case true when typeof(TDerived3).IsAssignableFrom(type):
        break;
}
```

Notice the `switch(true)` and `case(true)`. I recommend this simpler technique whenever you are relying only on the `when` clause (that is, beyond just the situation of switching on `System.Type` as discussed here).

Comment: I think you should swap the 2 things like this. It should be: typeof(TDerivedN).IsAssignableFrom(type). And also put case #3 first.

Comment: @N73k The order that I specified for `IsAssignableFrom` is correct. It is an instance method call on the ***lesser-derived*** `Type`. As you note, swapping the order is directly related to the order of the case statements, which therefore is also correct as specified.

Comment: Hmm. I don't think so. For example if type is a TDerived4 (where TDerived4 : TDerived3) then you'd want your last line (the one with "TDerived3") to be triggered. But no case statements get triggered because TDerived4 is not assignable from any of the TDeriveds in the case statements.

Comment: @N73k Mea culpa. I updated the answer to incorporate your correction.

Answer (score 23):

Starting with Paulustrious's idea of switching on a constant, but striving for the most readability:

```
  Type type = GetMyType();
  switch (true)
  {
    case bool _ when type == typeof(int):
      break;
    case bool _ when type == typeof(double):
      break;
    case bool _ when type == typeof(string):
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
```

What's readable is subjective. I used to do something similar in VB a long time ago so I got used to this form (but in VB the `bool _` was not needed so it wasn't there). Unfortunately in c# the `bool _` required. I'm using c# 7.0 and I think switching on a constant may not be supported in earlier compilers but I am not sure about that, so try it if you want to. I think it's kindof amusing that the S/O code formatter doesn't know about `when` yet.

You wouldn't want to do this of course if you need the `case` variable, like for subclasses.

But for arbitrary boolean expressions it is more suited, for example:

```
  switch (true)
  {
    case bool _ when extruder.Temperature < 200:
      HeatUpExtruder();
      break;
    case bool _ when bed.Temperature < 60:
      HeatUpBed();
      break;
    case bool _ when bed.Y < 0 || bed.Y > 300:
      HomeYAxis();
      break;
    default:
      StartPrintJob();
      break;
  }
```

Some will argue this is worse than if..else. The only thing I can say is `switch` forces one path and it's impossible to break the `switch` statement itself, but it is possible to leave out an `else` and break an if..else into multiple statements unintentionally, possibly executing two "branches" accidentally.

Switching on a `Type` is really just an arbitrary switch because what we are really switching on is a property of the variable. Unless and until we can do `case typeof(int)` (`case` on something that is not a constant expression), we are stuck with something akin to this if we don't want to use string constants, which in the case of type names, are not in the framework.

Comment: You pretty much covered it there. It is purely another way of if-then-else-if. But if we adopt that concept what is the purpose of any switch statement? It improves readability, less likely to forget a 'not' and as you say it catches the missing `else`. FYI. c# V7 is the first version to support this, and the first version where the order of the case statements makes any difference. I understand about your VB. I used Powerbuilder and that had a `choose` statement which gave you similar capabilities. Finally can have multiple 'ifs' in a when clause.

Comment: I had this same issue using my own types, this implementation really helped clean up what was a messy list of if-else-if-else statements.

Answer (score 17):

Although the question is on [C# 7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7) but for those with a [C# 8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8) version or higher, you can use the newer syntax which is shorter and I think is nicer as well.

```cs
type switch
{
    Type _ when type == typeof(int) || type == typeof(decimalType) =>
        this.value = Math.Max(Math.Min(this.value, Maximum), Minimum),
    _ => // default case
};
```

Another elegant option:

```cs
Type.GetTypeCode(type) switch
{
    TypeCode.Int32 or TypeCode.Decimal =>
        this.value = Math.Max(Math.Min(this.value, Maximum), Minimum),
    _ => // default case
};
```

For more info:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/switch-expression

Answer (score 4):

@toddmo suggested the following:

```
switch (true)
{
    case bool _ when extruder.Temperature < 200:
        HeatUpExtruder();
        break;

    // etc..
    default:
        StartPrintJob();
        break;
}
```

...but why not go even further in his pursuit of simplicity. The following works just as well without needing the `bool` type qualification, nor the extraneous `_` dummy variable:

```
switch (true)
{
    case true when extruder.Temperature < 200:
        HeatUpExtruder();
        break;

    // etc.
    default:
        StartPrintJob();
        break;
}
```

Comment: `case true when` is much more readable than `case bool _ when` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the above answer, if you do not need the value to be used inside the case statement, **you can use _**. This syntax can be used to remove an unused variable warning message.

```
switch (this.value) {
  case int _:
    //Do something else without value.
    break;
  case decimal decimalValue:
    this.value = Math.Max(Math.Min(decimalValue, Maximum), Minimum);
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not applicable in all cases, but maybe my example will help someone. In ASP.NET Core I implemented my custom model binder provider and I had to resolve binder type depending on model type.

The initial idea (apart from the if/else block ofc but I kept thinking it could be shorter) was the switch:

```
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        switch (context.Metadata.ModelType)
        {
            case Type _ when context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(Model1):
                return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(Binder1));
            case Type _ when context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(Model2):
                return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(Binder2));
            case Type _ when context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(Model3):
                return new BinderTypeModelBinder(typeof(Binder3));
        }

        return null;
    }
```

This is the same with a dictionary:

```
    public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
    {
        var bindersByType = new Dictionary<Type, Type>
        {
            {typeof(Model1),  typeof(Binder1)},
            {typeof(Model2),  typeof(Binder2)},
            {typeof(Model3),  typeof(Binder3)}
        };

        return bindersByType.TryGetValue(context.Metadata.ModelType, out Type binderType) ? new BinderTypeModelBinder(binderType) : null;
    }
```

Credits for the idea go to @xxbbcc who posted this in a comment to the first question

Answer (score -1):

I found a simple and efficient way. It requires C# V7 to run. The `switch("")` means all cases will be satisfied up to the `when` clause. It uses the `when` clause to look at the `type`.

```
List<Object> parameters = new List<object>(); // needed for new Action
parameters = new List<object>
{
    new Action(()=>parameters.Count.ToString()),
    (double) 3.14159,
    (int) 42,
    "M-String theory",
    new System.Text.StringBuilder("This is a stringBuilder"),
    null,
};
string parmStrings = string.Empty;
int index = -1;
foreach (object param in parameters)
{
    index++;
    Type type = param?.GetType() ?? typeof(ArgumentNullException);
    switch ("")
    {
        case string anyName when type == typeof(Action):
            parmStrings = $"{parmStrings} {(param as Action).ToString()} ";
            break;
        case string egStringBuilder when type == typeof(System.Text.StringBuilder):
            parmStrings = $"{parmStrings} {(param as System.Text.StringBuilder)},";
            break;
        case string egInt when type == typeof(int):
            parmStrings = $"{parmStrings} {param.ToString()},";
            break;
        case string egDouble when type == typeof(double):
            parmStrings = $"{parmStrings} {param.ToString()},";
            break;
        case string egString when type == typeof(string):
            parmStrings = $"{parmStrings} {param},";
            break;
        case string egNull when type == typeof(ArgumentNullException):
            parmStrings  = $"{parmStrings} parameter[{index}] is null";
            break;
        default: throw new System.InvalidOperationException();
    };
}
```

This leaves parmStrings containing...

`System.Action  3.14159, 42, M-String theory, This is a stringBuilder, parameter[5] is null`

Comment: You are switching on a string and whenning on a Type, instead of switching on a Type, is that faster? because it's a bit harder to follow. The person looking at it is scratching their head for a moment wondering what the case expressions mean (turns out they don't mean anything to the compiler, but the variable names make it seem as they do, as you are using them like comments, but this is not readily clear).

Comment: @toddmo You're right. I have looked at the code generated and it is simple. Far less expensive than some of the earlier solutiosn. I didn't consider that the variable names would cause confusion. But once you have seen it and understand, it's far easier next time you come across it. I use the String variable names as comments. Say there are four bool or bool? variables. I will call once case  TTFN. (N=null). The next, say TxxT is conditions 1 & 4 true and 2 & 3 are irrelevant. It makes it easy to find and of course you have the default to catch the ones you forgot.

Comment: You should add the code generated. That would be pretty interesting. Anyway, the true issue is deeper than confusing maintenance developers, and I'm not smart enough ATM to explain it. It has to do with doing things that the compiler won't enforce. I guess it would be more of an issue if the whenning variable wasn't `System.Type`, but some base type with many subclasses, like `System.Exception`, for example. At any rate, the "comment variables" can get out of sync with the whenning variable. And if you think they never would, you haven't met my co-workers lol

Comment: @toddmo. The only reason I used type in my whenning ways is that's what the OP requested. In another answer I will grab some of my real code. This however doesn't address the OP's question so it may get removed..

Comment: See my answer where I tried to eliminate the disadvantage of the confusing variable names and confusing switch expression.

Answer (score -1):

Well, it probably break your code convention, but I use this approach;

```
var result = this.Value is int intValue
? Math.Max(Math.Min(intValue, Maximum), Minimum)
: this.Value is decimal decimalValue
? Math.Max(Math.Min(decimalValue, Maximum), Minimum)
: this.Value is double doubleValue
? Math.Max(Math.Min(decimalValue, Maximum), Minimum)
: throw new Exception($"Cannot handle '{this.Value.GetType().Name}' value.");
```

You can use `Type.IsAssignableFrom()` in condition statement when it is more appropriate.

Comment: It wasn't a convention per se; it was just literally using the `switch` statement.

Answer (score -4):

Here is an alternative which won't compile as the classes are missing:

```
bool? runOnUI = queuedAction.RunOnUI;  // N=null, T=true F=False
bool isOnUI = Statics.CoreDispatcher.HasThreadAccess;
bool isFF = queuedAction.IsFireAndForget;   // just makes it easier to read the switch statement
if (false == queuedAction.IsFireAndForget)
    IsOtherTaskRunning = true;

/* In the case statements below the string name is something like noFF_TN
 * The compiler ignores the string name. I have used them here to represent
 * the logic in the case statement:   ( FF = FireAnd Forget, T=true, F=false, N = null, * means 'whatever')
 * 
 *      isFF_** = FireAndForget QueuedAction
 *      noFF_** = Not FireAndForget so Wait for Task to Finish (as opposed to Complete)
 *      ****_T* = We are already on the UI thread 
 *      ****_F* = We are not on the UI thread 
 *      ****_*T = Run on the UI thread.
 *      ****_*F = Do not run on UI thread
 *      ****_*N = Don't care so run on current thread
 *      
 *  The last character is a "bool?" representing RunOnUI. It has
 *  three values each of which has a different meaning */

bool isTask;
switch ("ignore")
{
    /* Run it as an Action (not Task) on current Thread   */
    case string noFF_TT when !isFF && isOnUI && runOnUI == true:
    case string isFF_TN when isFF && isOnUI && !runOnUI == null:
    case string isFF_FN when isFF && !isOnUI && runOnUI == null:
    case string isFF_TT when isFF && isOnUI && runOnUI == true:
    case string isFF_FF when isFF && !isOnUI && runOnUI == false:
        isTask = false;
        queuedAction.ActionQA(queuedAction); // run as an action, not as a Task
        break;

    /* Create a Task, Start it */

    case string isFF_TF when isFF && isOnUI == true && runOnUI == false:
    case string noFF_TN when !isFF && isOnUI == true && runOnUI == null:     // <== not sure if I should run it on UI instead
    case string noFF_TF when !isFF && isOnUI && runOnUI == false:
    case string noFF_FN when !isFF && !isOnUI && runOnUI == null:
    case string noFF_FF when !isFF && !isOnUI && runOnUI == false:
        var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
queuedAction.Canceller?.SetCancellationTokenSource(cancellationTokenSource);
        isTask = true;
        new Task
            (
                (action) => queuedAction.ActionQA(queuedAction),
                queuedAction,
                cancellationTokenSource.Token
            )
            .Start();
        break;

    /* Run on UI and don't wait */

    case string isFF_FT when isFF && !isOnUI && runOnUI == true:
        isTask = true;
        Statics.RunOnUI(() => queuedAction.ActionQA(queuedAction), asTaskAlways: true);
        break;

    /* Run on the UI as a Task and Wait */

    case string noFF_FT when !isFF && !isOnUI && runOnUI == true:
        isTask = true;
        Statics.RunOnUI(() => queuedAction.ActionQA(queuedAction), asTaskAlways: true);
        break;

    default:
        throw new LogicException("unknown case");
}
```