# Type switching on string type

Tags: c#

I have a class that parses stringified data into native data types (properties on itself). It iterates through the class properties and uses a switch statement that matches on the property type:

```
using System.Reflection;

…

class DataParser
{
    public int i { get; set; }
    public bool b { get; set; }
    public string s { get; set; }
    public DateTime d { get; set; }
    public Decimal e { get; set; }

    public DataParser()
    {
        PropertyInfo[] properties = this.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            object currentValue = property.GetValue(this);
            switch (currentValue)
            {
                case Int32 _:
                    …
                    break;
                case DateTime _:
                    …
                    break;
                case Decimal _:
                    …
                    break;
                case Boolean _:
                    …
                    break;
                case string _:
                    …
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new Exception($"Could not find type for {property.PropertyType}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Type matching works for all types except `string`, which throws with:

`Exception: Could not find type for System.String`

Perhaps it's not matching because `string` is a reference type? I've substituted the `string` case for `String` and `System.String`, same result.

**UPDATE**

As some folks suggested, the value of the string property was `null`. Setting a default value

`public string s { get; set; } = "";`

caused it to match.

Comment: I strongly suspect it's because the value is null. Null values don't match type patterns.

Comment: Try `case typeof(string):` instead of `case string:`

Comment: You probably ought to switch on `property.PropertyType`, not the concrete type of the value (which, as Jon points out, may not exist).

Comment: @Romain No, OP isn’t switching on a *type*, they’re switching on a *value* using C#’s new pattern matching syntax.

Comment: You can also use the [TypeCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.typecode?view=netframework-4.7.2) enum as `case TypeCode.String:`

Comment: your `property.GetValue(this)` returns `null`. `null` is **not** a string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43080505/c-sharp-7-0-switch-on-system-type